# How to upload large files from S3 to server without bloating Lambda memory?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm developing a pipeline that looks like this -

(NodeJS) File Upload -> S3 -> Lambda (written in nodejs, gets triggered from file:created event) -> Java Server (using CXF/JAX-RS). The hope is that the Lambda can avoid loading a large file into memory before forwarding it along to my Java server. There's metadata associated with the S3 file that I also need before contacting my Java server (so I can't just forward a stream, I need to check out the associated metadata and then forward the file contents along).

I've been reading through the AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property), which has lead me to believe that s3.getObject().createReadStream() is likely my best bet for loading the file contents without loading the entire file at once. I've noticed that createReadStream() can be piped, but I've not had any success getting the pipe to work as part of a multipart upload (which is what I think I need to do). It looks like the pipe() might only work with writable file streams.

```
var requestToJavaService = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log('Service Response statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('Service Response headers:', res.headers);

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      console.log('Service Response: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Connection to Service closed');
    });
    res.on('error', e => {
      callback(new Error(e));
      console.log('Encountered an error while attempting to connect     to Service: ' + e.message);
    });
  });

s3.getObject({ Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey })
    .createReadStream()
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('encountered error from s3 read: ' + err);
    })
    .pipe(
      requestToJavaService,
      { end: true }
    )
```

I'm not married to any of the ideas I've posed here, so any additional input/suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can your Java application download the file from S3, once provided the file information from Lambda? That way, you can send the metadata without the actual file contents. This will avoid requirements for large disk/memory storage.